# What is the workflow for maintaining a gem with regard to pushes to GitHub and RubyGems?

Tags: ruby, github, rubygems, workflow

Say one creates a repo, adds the necessary code, pushes the repo to GitHub, builds the gem via `gem build` and then pushes it to RubyGems via `gem push`. So far, so good. What is then the process to update the gem? What I mean is the following:

- If I make changes to the code and push them to GitHub is there an automatic way for RubyGems to detect the changes or do I need to run `gem build/push` again?
- Do I need to change the gem version on every git commit? I am aware of [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/), but what if I make changes, that are not related to the code of the gem directly, such as edits to the README, the .gemspec file etc.

So to sum it up - what is the workflow for maintaining a gem with regard to pushes to GitHub and RubyGems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in control here, the github commits are separate to `gem push`, unless you decide to link them with some automation (which is possible, but requires some effort and deliberate changes that you would need to make, so I am assuming you have not). I would not advise to link them and automatically release on a push to master branch, unless you are following a strict management of features and versioning, and have other automation to protect against mistakes, such as continuous integration.

Usually:

- The github code gets ahead of the published gem as you address issues and make changes.
- At some point, you decide to make a public release because enough has changed that it would be useful to share it in a new version.
- You then update the version data in the repo with a suitable commit
- You make a release (when I do this, I use the convenience `rake release`, but I think that just wraps a few steps including `gem build` and `gem push`)

RubyGems maintains records of each release for the gem. If you use versioning sensibly, then other people should be able to access previously-released versions of your gem.

Answer (score 1):

As Neil Slater says, git commits are separate from gem pushes.

However, I would add that it is good practice to [tag your master git branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) with the gem id

So say you are building a new thing. You have the following commit history

1. create the initial code
2. add some more functionality
3. fix a bug
4. finalize the first release code and push it as gem 0.0.1
5. add additional functionality and push it as gem 0.0.2
6. start work on a major change
7. finalize the major change and release as gem 0.1.0

So you have seven commits, and three gem releases. To tie those together you'd tag:

- commit 4 tag as 0.0.1
- commit 5 tag as 0.0.2
- commit 7 tag as 0.1.0

If you push those tags to github, they'll appear as releases.

Comment: Note this tagging is another thing that `rake release` does automatically (this is made part of your gem's Rakefile by default by Bundler if you start your gem with `bundle gem`)